# How to save newly created pivot items?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, pivotitem

I have a pivot application, in that I was adding dynamic pivot items, via following code.

```
    private void AddPivot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PivotItem pvt = new PivotItem();
        pvt.Header = "item";
        pvt.Content = AddNewStackPanel();
        MainPivot.Items.Add(pvt);
        pvt = null;
    }
```

So, Whenever I clicked this button, a new pivot item is being added in my application. But it's not being saved in the application. If I closed the app, and opens again, the items I have created were not shown in the app.

Hence, I need to know How to save the pivot items in the app itself for permanent use?

Answer (score 0):

You should treat them as settings and save them to IsolatedStorage for further use. You may check these two sites as a starting point:

http://jeffblankenburgdotcom.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj714090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: BTW, how can you save the UI element to the IsolatedStorage? You can save only the objects to the IsolatedStorageSettings!

Comment: Just save the data inside the pivot and when reloading, reload the data.

Comment: actually it will have nearly eight or more pivot items, every item will have nearly 25 UI elements. how can I save 8 x 25 = 200 datas into the isolated storage ?